# How does (x1,x2,x3) go to the origin?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the simple matrix equation $X'=AX$ where A is a matrix with $0's$ everywhere and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3$ on the main diagonal. All the lambda's are negative and $\lambda_3 <\lambda_2< \lambda_1$ .
The solution clearly tends to $(0,0,0)$ as $\lambda_3$ dominates but I want to answer to describe how the solution through an arbitrary
initial value tends to the origin

Comment: What do you mean "HOW a solution 'gets there'"?  The solution is simply the solution.  It is like saying $2 x = 10$ has the solution $x=5$... but HOW does it "get there"!

Comment: I meant to say "Describe how the solution through an arbitrary
initial value tends to the origin"

Comment: @David, the solution to this differential equation is a vector function of time, and as $t\to\infty$ it approaches the origin in some particular direction, and OP wants to know which direction.

Comment: @Ben, it's not a spiral.

Comment: No imaginary parts Ben, so it's not a spiral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution is $X=(c_1e^{\lambda_1t},c_2e^{\lambda_2t},c_3e^{\lambda_3t})$, where the $c_i$ reflect the initial condition. Assuming $c_1\ne0$, we can write this as $X=c_1e^{\lambda_1t}(1,(c_2/c_1)e^{(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)t},(c_3/c_1)e^{(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)t})$. The vector part approaches $(1,0,0)$ as $t\to\infty$, confirming your belief.

Comment: couldn't you have divided by any of the $ci's$? wouldn't that change the answer?>

Comment: Might as well add, since the question was about arbitrary initial conditions, that, if $c_1=0\neq c_2$ then the solution approaches $(0,0,0)$ tangentially to the $y$-axis, if $c_1=c_2=0\neq c_3$ then it converges along the $z$-axis, and if $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ then it just sits at $(0,0,0,)$.

Comment: The important part was dividing by $e^{\lambda_1t}$ and noticing that the second and third components of the quotient go to zero as $t\to\infty$, Jama, while the first component is a nonzero constant. Yes, you can divide by any $c_i$, or any nonzero number you like to divide by; no, it wouldn't change the answer, you would still get something going to zero times something approaching a point on the $x$-axis.

Comment: thanks,Gerry. Why did you divide by $e^{\lambda_1 t}$? The rest, of course, makes sense.

Comment: Andreas, I understand your last two cases, but for your first case, could you explain? $\lambda_3 < \lambda_2$ so why the $y$ axis. And why tangentially?

Comment: More accurate to say I factored out the $e^{\lambda_1t}$. I did that because that was the term going to zero the slowest, so it would leave two components still going to zero after I factored it out.

Comment: so the answer is that solution tends to origin tangentially to x-axis. Why is that?

Comment: The solution (if $c_1\ne0$) is of the form $f(t)(1,g(t),h(t))$ where $f,g,h$ all go to zero as $t\to\infty$. Isn't that the very definition of tending to the origin tangentially to the $x$-axis? Or would asymptotically be a better word than tangentially? How would *you* define "tends to the origin tangentially to the $x$-axis"?